# Tar Archive All Files with Extension

Tags: linux, find, tar, gzip

I'm using this command to archive all PHP files:

```
find -name "*.php" | sudo tar -zcpvf my-archive.tar.gz -T -
```

It works great, except that the output is like this:

```
./file1.php
./file2.php
./file3.php
```

Instead of:

```
file1.php
file2.php
file3.php
```

How do I need to modify my command so that ./ is not included in my archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most versatile tool to control the output of find is its own -printf feature. It has the %P sequence whose function is

```
  %P     File's  name  with  the name of the command line argument
         under which it was found removed.


find -name '*.php' -printf "%P\n"
```

is the same as

```
find ./ -name '*.php' -printf "%P\n"
```

so ./ is removed from the beginning of each line

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. I mistakenly thought it had to do something with the tar command but it was actually the find command.